# When is this voltage source activated?

Tags: passive-networks

So I'm doing first order circuit analysis and I stumbled upon a circuit which had this as a voltage source:

[image]

When would this voltage source be active?

For example in this circuit:

[image]

The current source on the left would be active at *t>1*.
The one on the right is active at *t>0*.

What about that voltage source though?

Comment: The voltage source is active at all t < 0 (I am guessing there is a switching mechanism in the circuit?). You can see that by plotting u(t) and letting t > -t, you will see how the step function is reflected along the y-axis.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So would it also be inactive for t>0?

Comment: I think it is used to represent initial conditions, since it is active till just before t = 0 ( or zero minus as it is called ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\$u(t)\$ is the [Unit Step Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). More than a mathematical function is a tool that allows us to model activations and deactivations in electrical circuits and abrupt changes of state in general. This function is defined as

$$
u(t) = \left\lbrace
\begin{matrix}
0 \qquad t<0 \\
1 \qquad t>0
\end{matrix}
\right.
$$

For your question, the variable \$t\$ has been transformed by a reflection with respect to \$t = 0\$. This means that

$$
u(-t) = \left\lbrace
\begin{matrix}
0 \qquad t > 0 \\
1 \qquad t < 0
\end{matrix}
\right.
$$

What does this mean? It means that the power supply has been active from \$t = -\infty\$ to \$t = 0\$, when it was deactivated. In other words, this source *should only be taken into account in determining the initial conditions* in the analysis of the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion consider a change of variable: \$u(x) = 1\$ when \$x \geq 0\$, and \$u(x) = 0\$ when \$x < 0\$. This is simply the definition of the step function with \$x\$ as the independent variable rather than the usual \$t\$.

In this case you have \$u(-t)\$. Looking at the argument to the step function: \$-t = x\$. Substituting from the definition above \$u(x) = u(-t) = 1\$ when \$x = -t \geq 0\$ and \$u(x) = u(-t) = 0\$ when \$x = -t < 0\$. Divide both sides of the inequalities by \$-1\$ and you have \$u(-t) = 1\$ when \$t < 0\$ and \$u(-t) = 0\$ when \$t \geq 0\$. In other words, the source is on when \$t < 0\$ (i.e. it turns off at \$t = 0\$) and then is off for all \$t \geq 0\$.

Comment: Thank you for answering but I'm sorry. Would you explain to me your first sentence? Or tell me what should I look into to understand it? it seems like simple math and I feel dumb.

Comment: @OsamaKerem No need to feel dumb. I've updated my answer to explain a bit more. Let me know if you need any further clarification.